# Отправка индивидуального файла в telegram bot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

не знаю как сделать что бы открывало индивидуальный файл пользователя и отправляло ему его "телефонную книгу" (новичок, обучаюсь)

```
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def msg(message):
    file_name = str(message.from_user.id)  + ".txt"
    f = open(file_name, 'a')
    f.write(message.text + ' \n')
    f.close()
    markap = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Посмотреть список контактов', callback_data='qq')
    markap.add(item)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь добавлен в книгу ✅', reply_markup=markap)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'qq':
            with open("f{user.id}.txt",'r') as file:
                content = file.read()
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Список контактов: \n{content}')
```

Comment: что именно не получается? апи телеграма позволяет отправить файл. почитайте в документации библиотеки которую используете, наверняка есть.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятен вопрос, ведь в коде все работает. Если вы хотите сделать рассылку пользователям какой-то их личной информации, то сделайте список пользователей

```py
Users = []
```

и добавляйте в этот список пользователей после сообщения, если его там не было

```py
 @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def msg(message):
    isInUsers = False
    for(i in Users):
        if(message.from_user.id == i):
            isInUser = True
    if(not isInUser):
        Users.append(message.from_user.id)
    file_name = str(message.from_user.id)  + ".txt"
    f = open(file_name, 'a')
    f.write(message.text + ' \n')
    f.close()
    markap = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Посмотреть список контактов', callback_data='qq')
    markap.add(item)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь добавлен в книгу ✅', reply_markup=markap)
```

далее можете делать рассылку, проверять пользователя на наличие в базе и т. д.
P.S. этот список лучше тоже записать в отдельный файл

Comment: Спасибо, исправил